# How to reset&clear the contents of Modal on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Modal with some contents on it. When i click the cancel button, I want to clear and reset the contents of the modal. But the problem i face is, When i click the cancel button and reopen the modal, the contents still remain on the Modal.

I have attached the image of the Modal:

Before clicking Cancel Button:

[image]

After Clicking Cancel Button and reopening the modal, the contents still remain inside modal from the previous time, the image below shows it:

[image]

I have attached the code below:

HTML:

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <div id="imagearea" class="imagearea">
      <div class='dynamic_text' style='display:none;'></div>

    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="fashion.jpg">

    </div>
      <div class="text_container">

        <br>
        <div class="img_text">

        </div>
        <div class="input_tag">
          <span class="right_sec_text">Select a region from the picture</span>
          <div class="error"></div>

          <div class="tags" id ="tags"></div>
          <div class="input_box">
            <input type="text" name="tags" id="name_tag" class="input_textbox">
            <button id="settag" class="btn_settag">Set Tag</button>
          </div>
                      
          <div class="footer_btn">
            <p><button class="btn_success" id="btn_add" value="add areas">Confirm Selection</button>
            <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

this is the code for the cancel button:

```
  <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide()">Cancel</button>
```

I have included this code :
Javascript:

```
            $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {     $(this).removeData(); });
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem to reset and close the modal window.

Comment: `.hide()` will only hide the element by changing its css `display` property to `none`. You still need to clear the contents of the modal before hiding it.

Comment: @saulmaldonado can u show me how to do it

Comment: @saulmaldonado I have edited my code, but this time the modal doesnt close

Comment: you can use `.html('')` to clear html entities inside of an element.

Comment: @msc can you show me how its done ?

Comment: If you want to remove the values from input tag, then you can enclose the tags in a form and give it id='myForm'.  Then onclick of cancel button, you can reset the form like this.  <p><button class="btn_cancel" onclick="$('#myModal').hide();$('#myForm').trigger('reset');">Cancel</button>